# Vuetify.js/Vue.js: Variable in props in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js

I am iterating over a list (I'm using Vue.js 2 and Vuetify) and I want to have multiple `<v-sheet>` that have different colors. I've tried:

```
<v-sheet v-for="color in schema.colors" :key="color" class="float-left"
  color="`${color}`"
  elevation="1"
  height="40"
  width="40"
></v-sheet>
```

but that doesn't set `color` to the appropriate value.

I've also tried `color="{{ color }}"`, without success. The `color` variable is set to a valid value, i.e. `#1234ab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign variables then you need to use the bind syntax (see the colon before color)

```
<v-sheet v-for="color in schema.colors" :key="color" class="float-left"
  :color="color"
  elevation="1"
  height="40"
  width="40"
></v-sheet>
```